# How do I press F8 on my 2016 Macbook Pro?

Tags: mac

It would be great to figure out how to press F8, or trigger a pause of JavaScript execution via the keyboard on my computer that has no F8 key.

Answer (score 4):

The information you are looking for is on [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240).

To use any function key, you hold <kbd>fn</kbd>, and the touch bar should switch to display the function keys.

It's actually not much different from any other keyboard without a Touch Bar, where holding <kbd>fn</kbd> will switch the function between the media keys and the function keys.

The [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240) also mentions that you can make the function keys display permanently in specific apps in 'System Preferences' > 'Keyboard' > 'Shortcuts'

and that alternatively, you can use the on-screen keyboard.